# In ActionScript 3 (AIR application), using stageDisplayState to go full screen only doesn't maximize whole stage, just certain elements

Tags: flash, actionscript, air, fullscreen

I am building an AIR application for my employer using Flash CS 5.5. The application will be installed on a Mac Mini attached to a Planar touch screen display in portrait orientation (1080x1920). I want to be able to run the app in full screen mode with no toolbars/titlebars visible, but I'm running into this snag:

On one of my layers I have an flvPlayback instance that plays videos based on user input. When I use `stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE` instead of making the whole stage full screen, it makes the flvPlayback element fullscreen and everything else on the stage disappears.

I have tried executing this command from a mouseclick, from a timer, and just on application startup, and I get this problem every time. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FLVPlayback` has a property called `fullScreenTakeOver` (which defaults to true).

If you set it to false it should resolve your problem.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm a php developer who got thrown into this project. Your help is GREATLY appreciated.